# Netty client bootstrap connection fails

Tags: java, io, netty

I am building a client / server with Netty 4.0.
The server is listening properly on localhost:8083 and I can telnet on it, it triggers server breakpoints properly.
But when I try to connect with that piece of code :

```
_bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
_bootstrap.group(locGroup)
    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
    .handler(new ClientInit(this, _sslContext, _logger));
_bootstrap.remoteAddress("127.0.0.1", 8083);
ChannelFuture locChannelFuture = _bootstrap.connect();
_channel = locChannelFuture.sync().channel();
```

It throws an exception at sync() : java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException.
As said before, when I telnet 127.0.0.1 8083 (or connect in code with a Socket), it does work.
Any idea ? Thank you.

Comment: Could you show your pipeline with more details on both sides (server and client), in order to see what kind of handler are there? For instance, I see _sslContext, which I suppose is to manage ssl part, which could be a cause of refused connection and then a ClosedChannelException. Also the stack trace could be useful.

Comment: The pipeline was indeed the key. I explained that in my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it.
The problem was simply that I gave NioServerSocketChannel as the default channel class to the bootstrap constructor. Building a client, I put NioSocketChannel instead, and it's working fine.

So, here is the correct one :

```
_bootstrap.group(locGroup)
    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
    .handler(new ClientInit(this, _sslContext, _logger));
```

Comment: So obvious I didn't see it!